# How to make padding?

Tags: html, css

I have next HTML:

```
<div>
  <b>Text</b>
  <br>next line
</div>
```

I try to make padding after first line, but neither work:

```
div > :first-child {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}


div > :first-child {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

How to make padding after first line?

Comment: Make it (the `<b>`) `display: inline-block ` ... or `display: block` and you can get rid of the `<br>`

Comment: @LGSon: Create the answer I will accept it

Comment: Linked it instead, as those answers are as good as it gets :)